# create new array from old array column

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to OOP, but I'm trying to create my first bigger program. 
I've read a txt-file and stored the  values (doubles) into an array, I call it originalArray. The text has two columns and 20 lines. So when I want to print the values in the first column of the txt-file I simply write:

```
 System.out.println(originalArray[0]);

 OUTPUT: 1991.00
         300.50
         498.50 .... et cetera...
```

My problem is that i'd like to use a for-loop (or whatever) to create two new arrays, each consisting one column from the "original array".

I thought it would be as simple as using a for-loop, like this;

```
  double [] newArray = new double [20]; 

  for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++){

  newArray[i] = originalArray[0] //if I want to fill it with the first       

  //columns data... the second would be newArray2[i] = originalArray[1]
   }
```

But this fills the new array with ONE element from the column in the originalArray... So - I need help to figure of how to write the loop to fill the new arrays with all elements from one chosen column.

Very grateful for help!

Regards/ frustrated newbie

EDIT: This is how I read the txt file:

```
String file = "C:\\Users\\komena\\Desktop\\30th-sales.csv";

 BufferedReader br = null;
 String line = "";
 String splitBy = ";";

originalArray = new double [20]; 
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
br.readLine();//skip the first line to get rid of header…  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

String[] readlineArray = line.split(splitBy);

for (int i = 0; i < readlineArray.length; i++) {
originalArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(readlineArray[i]);

}
```

Whole text (csv) file:

```
300.50;330.00
489.50;296.50
34.50;399.50
900.00;1890.00
2052.00;568.00
354.00;0.00
399.00;0.00
1299.50;0.00
426.00;259.00
29.50;2300.50
99.50;349.50
2500.50;0.00
358.50;113.00
789.00;239.50
998.00;348.00
16.50;679.00
800.00;723.00
1899.50;950.50
550.50;568.00
```

Comment: Do you have all the data of the first column in `originalArray[0]`? What is the type of `originalArray`?

Comment: They are both double. When I read the file I first read it to a String array, then parsed it to a double. I need to use the arrays for calculating the values later on, that's why Ii need to separate the columns in to two arrays.  (will analyze each column).

Comment: 1991.00,
300.50,
489.50,
34.50,
900.00,
2052.00,
354.00,
399.00,
1299.50,
426.00,
29.50,
99.50,
2500.50,
358.50,
789.00,
998.00,
16.50,
800.00,
1899.50,
550.50 // the data of originalArray[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new 2D array with the size of the 1st dimension the same as the `originalArray`'s length and the 2nd dimension the size of 2 (2 columns). Then simply loop it and add the old values to one column and also the new ones if reuqired, otherwise they will be set as `0.0` defaultly.

```
double originalArray[] = {1991.00, 300.50, 498.50};
double newArray[][] = new double[originalArray.length][2];
for (int i=0; i<originalArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i][0] = i                              // Fill the 1st column with sth like ID
    newArray[i][1] = originalArray[i];              // Copy the 1D array to the 2nd column
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray));  // Print all the array values
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 1991.00], 
 [2.0, 300.50], 
 [3.0, 498.50]]
```

---

Moreover you read the file wrong. Notice that you have 2 values in the each line separated with `;` and lines separated with `\n`. So read the line by line and add 2 values to the array.

The `i` variable represents the actual index of the `originalArray[]`.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
int i=0;
double originalArray[] = new double[20]; 
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
br.readLine();//skip the first line to get rid of header…  

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i<originalArray.length) {
    String[] readlineArray = line.split(";");
    originalArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(readlineArray[0]);
    originalArray[i+1] = Double.parseDouble(readlineArray[1]);
    i+=2;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalArray));
```

Comment: Your code makes all sence, but I think I might have done something wrong when reading my file because now my output looks like;           [[0.0, 1991.00], [1.0, 300.50], [2.0, 0.0], [3.0, 0.0], [4.0, 0.0], [5.0, 0.0], [6.0, 0.0], [7.0, 0.0], [8.0, 0.0], [9.0, 0.0], [10.0, 0.0], [11.0, 0.0], [12.0, 0.0], [13.0, 0.0], [14.0, 0.0], [15.0, 0.0], [16.0, 0.0], [17.0, 0.0], [18.0, 0.0], [19.0, 0.0], [20.0, 0.0]]

Comment: To help you, I'd have to see the way you read the values from the file. Anyway try to use debugger, because the problem is that some values are missing in the `originalArray[]` indeed.

Comment: One more thing... Would it be possible to instead of reading the data to originalArray[], fill newArray1[] and newArray2[] with the file-data? Can you fill two arrays in the while-loop?? (instead of one i.e.)

Comment: Of course, feel free to try it yourself. I managed my question in order to solve the original issue copying the 1D array into the 2D one.